# How to remove or update rules from older versions of Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I somehow have a rule that's filtering important messages to a weird folder, but there are no *visible* rules that match that folder. But there is a warning sign that says:

> There are rules created with a different version of Outlook or Outlook Web Access that are not shown.

How do I delete or modify those rules?

Answer (score 4):

Log into Outlook Web Access. Select **Options** then **All Options** (or whatever it might be called), **Organize E-Mail** and then **Inbox Rules**.

I had rules listed here, not listed in Outlook proper.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the Office 365 portal.

Microsoft describes it under [Inbox Rules in Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Inbox-rules-in-Outlook-edea3d17-00c9-434b-b9b7-26ee8d9f5622). Reproduced for convenience.

> To manage rules:
>
> 1. In a web browser, sign in to Outlook Web App using the URL provided by the person who manages email for your organization. Enter your user name and password, and then click **Sign in**.
> 2. At the top of the page, choose **Outlook** (or **Mail**). Or, choose the **app launcher [the grid icon]** > **Mail**.
> 3. At the top of the page, select **Settings [the gear icon]** > **Options**.
>
> In **Options**, select **Organize email** > **Inbox rules**. Or, in **Options**, under **MAIL** > **Automatic processing**, select **Inbox rules**.

And then:

> If you have a rule that you no longer want, you can select it and then click delete [trash can icon] to remove it. If you just want to turn the rule off for a while, remove the check mark next to the rule.

Comment: I foolishly tried out the "New Outlook" and a rule I made there was stopping rule execution I guess. Couldn't see it after I downgraded back to normal desktop outlook. Was able to fix it with the web client. Thanks!